# "oursql" python library installation issue on windows

Tags: python

I am trying to install oursql for flask based project and I get this dependency error related to Cython but Cython is installed and I can import it fine in shell. I've upgraded pip and virtualenv but couldn't get oursql installed on windows OS. If someone can suggest a solution that would be a relief and I am trying to find a way around for windows. Following is error:

```
(genzconnect) C:\Users\AliKhan\connectspace\connectproject>pip3 install oursql
Collecting oursql
  Using cached oursql-0.9.3.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\AliKhan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5jo_6fot\oursql\setup
.py", line 53
        print "cython not found, using previously-cython'd .c file."
                                                                   ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AliKhan
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5jo_6fot\oursql\
```

Comment: I recommend `mysqlclient` rather than `oursql` and the error message seems the library doesn't support python3.

Comment: There has to be a way around because ultimately my client will upload it on Ubuntu server and this package is listed in requirement for future expansions. Also same error on python2.

Comment: The error is not related to Cython but to the Python 2 `print` syntax which won't work with Python 3.  As it is Python 2 syntax it is _very_ unlikely you get the same error with Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

For python3.x try-

```
pip3 install oursql3
```